# Venturi effect and turbojet engine

Tags: pressure

Turbojet engine uses its blades to push air through a smaller volume to compress the air for the combustion.

I'm know getting confused of the fact that in Venturi effect the flowing fluid forced to a smaller volume should decrease the pressure of the fluid.

What am i not getting here?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting mixed up between the venturi effect on the aerodynamics of aircraft and how their  modern engines operate.

[Venturi Effect Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venturi_effect#Examples)

> The Bernoulli Principle and its corollary, the Venturi effect, are essential to aerodynamic as well as hydrodynamic design concepts. Airfoil and hydrofoil designs to lift and steer air and water vessels (airplanes, ships and submarines) are derived from applications of the Bernouoli Principle and the Venturi effect, as are the instruments that measure rate of movement through the air or water (velocity indicators). Stability indication and control mechanisms such as gyroscopic altitude indicators and fuel metering devices, such as carburetors, function as a result of gas or fluid pressure differentials that create suction as demonstrated and measurable by gas/fluid pressure and velocity equations derived from the Bernoulli Principle and the Venturi Effect.

[image]

Image Source: [Turbine Engines Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_turbine)

Look at these images of tubine engines and remember that the main flow from the compressed fan at the front is designed to bring air into the middle of the engine.

Look at how  small the difference in diameter is between the combustion chamber and the diameter of the rest of the engine.  The venturi effect is limited (actually it's non existent) and  nothing resembling the venturi constriction points of garden hoses, domestic appliances etc.

Aircraft designers have an inbuilt urge to reduce weight, they are always on the lookout to save a kilo or 10. If the difference in diameter was significant to aid the effect, then they would taper the engine, which they don't,  because there is no venturi effect.

Number 4 is a high bypass engines, that big rotor shunts air around the combustion chamber, never into it. That's what keeps modern aircraft relativly quiet and gives the funny UFO types noises you sometimes hear.

Finally, look at the Wikipedia entry on gas turbines, I couldn't see anything about venturi effect utilisation. I then looked up the venturi effect on Wikipedia and could not see anything about aircraft engines applications.

Answer (score 1):

The venturi effect is irrelevant here, because at the exit from the compressor there is a combustion chamber, which adds a lot of heat energy (and therefore a lot of pressure) to the gas before it leaves the engine and generates the thrust.

In fact most of the work done by the compressor is stopping the gas from the combustion chamber escaping from the *front* of the engine, instead of from the back. This is what happens when the combustion chamber wins the fight ... and on a really bad day, flames come out of the front of the engine as well as the back!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mQNUrYoFM2E

Comment: If you are flying soon, you may not want to watch this video, birds and turbines don't mix https://youtu.be/lgspIiTFWIk